# Google Cloud Identity Aware Proxy (App Engine) - Strange web browser behavior?

Tags: google-chrome, security, google-app-engine, firefox, curl

I am seeing some strange behavior using App Engine with Identity Aware Proxy in Chrome (Desktop & Mobile) / Firefox (Desktop & Mobile) / Safari (Desktop) / curl (Desktop)

I launched a static-file site on App Engine using these settings

app.yaml:

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /(.*)
  static_files: index.html
  upload: index.html
  secure: always
```

index.html:

```
<html>
<body>
Hello World!
</body>
</html>
```

I then used the cloud console to enable the Identity Aware Proxy.

As expected, I was asked to sign in using the google account needed to access the page. All good.

However, sometimes I can access the site from a browser without credentials, or even from `curl`, which I feel should definitely not be possible?

It takes a bunch of refreshes / retries, but once it is reproduced I can reliably get the index page without authentication using Chrome, Firefox, Opera, and `curl`.

Questions:

- Am I doing something completely stupid? Is it expected behavior to sometimes be able to access the page even in incognito/private mode, or using `curl`?
- I know there is a default 10 minute caching header on static files served by App Engine, how does that factor in?
- How does `curl` get mixed up in all of this? AFAIK https can not be cached by anyone except the UA making the request (and internally on Google's end)? Is there a cache on my computer that all of these sources talk to that I am not aware of?
- Is this a problem on my computer/phone (i.e. once the page is cached somehow all UAs on that device can see the page without authenticating)?
- Is this a problem on Google's end?

For completeness, here's the output from `curl -v`

```
curl -v https://xxxxxxxxxxxx.appspot.com
* Rebuilt URL to: https://xxxxxxxxxxxx.appspot.com/
*   Trying 172.217.22.180...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to xxxxxxxxxxxx.appspot.com (172.217.22.180) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=California; L=Mountain View; O=Google Inc; CN=*.appspot.com
*  start date: Mar 28 14:17:04 2018 GMT
*  expire date: Jun 20 13:24:00 2018 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "xxxxxxxxxxxx.appspot.com" matched cert's "*.appspot.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Google Trust Services; CN=Google Internet Authority G3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x7ff81780a400)
> GET / HTTP/2
> Host: xxxxxxxxxxxx.appspot.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS updated)!
< HTTP/2 200
< date: Fri, 20 Apr 2018 17:43:10 GMT
< expires: Fri, 20 Apr 2018 17:53:10 GMT
< etag: "8wDEQg"
< x-cloud-trace-context: 8e9c1b6803383aac532d48d9f0ac5fc2
< content-type: text/html
< content-encoding: gzip
< server: Google Frontend
< cache-control: public, max-age=600
< content-length: 54
< age: 371
< alt-svc: hq=":443"; ma=2592000; quic=51303433; quic=51303432; quic=51303431; quic=51303339; quic=51303335,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="43,42,41,39,35"
<
���(�ͱ�I�O���
* Connection #0 to host xxxxxxxxxxxx.appspot.com left intact
I-.Q�ч�l�!����Z�_$%
```

The output above SHOULD show a 302 redirect to IAP's login page, but as previously stated - it does not always do that!

TL;DR Why can I access App Engine static pages protected by IAP on my computer from contexts that should not be allowed access?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, you've run into an interesting corner case! There's some documentation of this at https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/concepts-best-practices -- TL;DR, App Engine does some caching for static_files that interacts poorly with IAP. That page has some instructions you can apply if you want to protect your static_files.  --Matthew, Google IAP Engineering

Comment: Thank you for your answer, as far as I can tell the documentation suggests to set the cache time to 0 seconds?